# Type cast operators to any arithmetic type except some reference

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

Let's say we have such an example class:

```
class Union {
    union Value {
        int i;
        float f;
    };
    enum class Type {
        Int, Float
    };
    Type type;
    Value value;

public:
    operator int&() { return value.i; }
    operator float&() { return value.f; }

    template <typename T, is_arithmetic<T>>
    operator T() const {
        if (type == Type::Int)
            return static_cast<T>(value.i);
        else
            return static_cast<T>(value.f);
    }
}
```

I want to allow Union instances to be casted to any arithmetic type but forbid to be casted to reference except some like int and float types in the example. For the given example compiler notifies about existing more than one conversion. How to deal with such a problem? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution like implementing the given operators:

```
operator int&();
operator float&();
operator T();
operator T() const;
```

With this set of operators I am able to define arithmetic variables like I did expect i.e. non-const, const, const reference and extra reference for specific types like int and float.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `is_arithmetic<T>`. It does not what you think it does. That is a template non-type parameter. `is_arithmetic` is a class, a type.

Think of it like this:

```
template <class T, int N>
struct X {};
```

And you can also omit the parameter name:

```
template <class T, int>
struct X {};
```

Now instead of `int` you have `is_arithmetic<T>`.

Get rid of it and it works:

```
template <typename T>
operator T() const {
```

My opinion is that you don't need to make sure `T` is an arithmetic type, as `static_cast` does that for you.

If you want to enforce that in the declaration, you need SFINAE and `enable_if`, that is until we have concepts:

```
template <class T, class Enable = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>>
operator T() const {
```

---

I also have some concerns with your design. Implicit casts are bad as a rule of thumb. So you might at least make them explicit.

Comment: The way I wrote is_arithmetic<T> was more like pseudocode to not bloat the example with unnecessary code. I will present solution I made up in an answer.

Comment: Yet I appreciate your explanation about templates.